# How to use Activity Indicator with RadSideDrawer on root level?

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Good day to everyone.
I am working on NativeScript Angular and i have  `ActivityIndicator`  at root level `app.component.html` . I also have `RadSideDrawer`  which is only for iOS. The ActivityIndicator works fine for iOS only when i remove the Sidedrawer.

I have attached my code snippet below for `app.component.html`

```
<AbsoluteLayout width="100%" height="100%">
    <page-router-outlet width="100%" height="100%" top="0" left="0" actionBarVisibility="never"></page-router-outlet>
    
    <ActivityIndicator androidElevation="12" [busy]="busy" [top]="screenHeight" [left]="screenWidth"
    class="primary-color" width="50" height="50">
    </ActivityIndicator>
</AbsoluteLayout>


<RadSideDrawer *ngIf="radScreen" [drawerTransition]="sideDrawerTransition">

    <GridLayout tkDrawerContent rows="auto, *"
        class="sidedrawer sidedrawer-left">
        <StackLayout row="0" class="sidedrawer-header">
            <Image  [src]="imageUrl" class="avatar" ></Image>
            <Label class="studentInfo rr-18" [text]="student?.name"></Label>
            <Label class="studentInfoSec rr-18" [text]="student?.studentId"></Label>
        </StackLayout>

        <ScrollView row="1">
            <StackLayout class="sidedrawer-content">
                <GridLayout columns="auto, *" class="sidedrawer-list-item" (tap)="onTranscriptTap()">
                    <Image col="0" class="drawerImg" src="res://transcript" ></Image>
                    <Label col="1"  text="Transcript" class="rr-18"></Label>
                </GridLayout>

                <GridLayout columns="auto, *" class="sidedrawer-list-item" (tap)="onSettingsTap()">
                    <Image col="0" class="drawerImg" src="res://settings" ></Image>
                    <Label col="1"   text="Settings" class="rr-18"></Label>
                </GridLayout>


                <GridLayout columns="auto, *" class="sidedrawer-list-item" >
                    <Image col="0" class="drawerImg" src="res://logout" ></Image>
                    <Label col="1" (tap)="onLogoutTap()"  text="Logout" class="rr-18 "></Label>
                </GridLayout>

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </GridLayout>
    <page-router-outlet tkMainContent class="page page-content">
    </page-router-outlet>

</RadSideDrawer>
```

Comment: What is your parent layout, the one that holds AbsoluteLayout and RadSideDrawer?

Comment: I didn’t create any parent layout, the absolute layout i used for Activity Indicator and RadSideDrawer as it is

Comment: By default it will be a content view, so as soon you add RadSideDrawer, the previous absolute layout will be removed from UI. Try wrapping them by a Grid layout.

Comment: So it should be like this ? 
<GridLayout>
 < AbsoluteLayout>
 </AbsoluteLayout>

< RadSideDrawer>
</RadSideDrawer>
</GridLayout>

Comment: I would recommend `<GridLayout><RadSideDrawer></RadSideDrawer>< ActivityIndicator></ActivityIndicator></GridLayout>`, then you can align the activity indicator to center of screen using layout alignments.

Comment: @Manoj if i do it that way, where will i put `page-router-outlet`

Comment: @Manoj i tried it the way you mentioned, however the ios screen went to full white